# What is the best way to update a big number of accounts

Tags: facebook, limits

I need your expert advice on this one.

I have been asked to analyse a potential Facebook application.

This application is a parental monitoring for kids accounts. Basically it will search a kid status message for specific keywords amongst others things. And this application will alert the parents when it finds something.

Of course this application will have a valid token to access the kid's data. This is not a tool to spy on the kid.

I am using the Graph API coupled with the 'since' keyword to get the last updates. It's working fine with a single user.

My question is about scalability. 
**How should I get updates of a huge number of kids to monitor?** (between 10,000 and 100,000 accounts)

And for each kids I have to monitor status messages, videos, images, friend, friends' status messages...

Here are some numbers:

~2.1M requests each day to get hourly updates of 10,000 kids' account.

~57.8M requests each day to get hourly updates of 10,000 kids'account plus their friends', with an average of 40 friends each.

And as I read [here](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=210701362295828), it would be limited.

So what do you reckon?

ps: Maybe with real-time updates I won't have this problem or would it be worse?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I would subscribe to real-time updates so as an account gets updated you get a callback and then you get the latest updates.  This would avoid the overhead of constantly polling accounts for updates.  You will need to get an offline_access token for this to work as well.

Comment: Do you know if the number of updates sent by facebook to a facebook application is limited like the API requests?
Will I be able to get updates for 10,000+ accounts?

Comment: You should be able to get updates about as many users as have approved your application.  You may then be rated limited getting the users feeds but you could wait and try again later for that user since you know where there are indeed updates that need to be retrieved.

Comment: I finally tried the real-time API. And it returns a notification object and not directly the object that has triggered the update. So in the end, I still have to make a request to pull the object.
Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: Yes but you will save all the API calls of hourly checking for any updates.